# Autodoc Error when using Sphinx with Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am attempting to use sphinx autodoc in a Django project, but keep recieving the same error.
My project is structured somewhat like so:

```
|project
|---app
|------models.py
|---docs
|------build
|------source
|---------conf.py
|etc
```

the top of my conf.py file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```

and my models.rst file looks like this:

```
Models
======
.. automodule:: project.app.models
    :members:
```

However, whenever I run `make html`, I get the one line error:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'app.models' from module 'project'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'project.app'
```

Any suggestions? Is this an issue with my sphinx configuration, or an issue with the django project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my models.rst to look like:

```
Models
======
.. automodule:: app.models
    :members:
```

fixed the issue.